# Mobile smooth scrolling with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scroll, smoothing

i'm creating a web with bootstrap, and I would like to add an smooth scrolling effect. It works perfectly on the desktop, but in the mobile version when you click on a link of the menu the scroll is much larger than the beginning of the section.

I'm using this code:

```
// Smooth scrolling
  $(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top -60
    }, 1000);
  });

// Closes responsive menu when a scroll trigger link is clicked
  $('.js-scroll-trigger').click(function() {
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
  });

// Activate scrollspy to add active class to navbar items on scroll
  $('body').scrollspy({
    target: '#mainNav',
    offset: 60
  });
```

You can check the test page at: http://pruebas.mareaestudio.com/raposo/

Thanks

Comment: comment this line `//$('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');` and see what you'll get .. I think `offset().top` calculated before `'.navbar-collapse'` completely hidden .. so you need to hide it before calculate `offset().top`

Comment: Yes, in effect, commenting on that part calculates the scroll correctly, how can I hide the `'.navbar-collapse'` before calcute `offset().top`?
Thank you.

Comment: I am also trying with the code on this page: https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-scrolling-nav/ that works perfectly, but on my page it keeps giving me the same problem

Comment: I've noticed that this happens by not entering the "fixed-top" class in the <nav>. Since I have a top bar, I have the <nav> in "sticky". Any ideas to solve the problem?